# CriteriaBuilder Query breaks when using fetch but works without

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have an method to fetch one single Element eager. For this i want to use id. If i use (root.fetch) to load eager, this query results in null results. But without it , it works! Why?

```
@Override
public Request getRequestById(int id) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Request> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Request.class);
    Root<Request> root = criteriaQuery.from(Request.class);
    Predicate equals = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id);
    root.fetch("products",JoinType.INNER);
    root.fetch("productiveShifts",JoinType.INNER);
    criteriaQuery.where(equals);
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery.select(root)).getResultList().get(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats simple - there are no `products` or `productiveShifts` associated with `root` thus empty result set. Remember that you are using INNER JOIN there, so association MUST exist.

If you would use Left Join on the other hand, it would probably work as expected.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Had no idea about joins, switching to left join was the exact solution. Thank you!